# android kotlin retrofit debug - Unable to open request data

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

I have provided picture so you don't need to read novels here. This happens for a long time, I have updated android studio, I have even changed the laptop (currently I use macbook pro 16) but issue remains. It just says: "Collecting data..." and stays like that.

Is this standard for android studio lately? I remember that before (few years ago) this was never happening.

[image]

Comment: you can use Log.e or log.d to check your response

Comment: @AyazMuhammad sure there are also other alternatives, but they are more time consuming and worse than this option that does not work. I don't need alternative solution I want this one because it is the best way :D